# Writing an inverse function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, lambda, functional-programming

I ran into a situation at work today where I needed to write the inverse of a function that I had already written, but I found it inefficient to write the inverse manually because it seems like I would be repeating a lot of my code, and if I were to update the original function I would have to update the inverse with the corresponding changes. The function I am talking about looks something like this:

```
var f = function(id, str) {
  if (id === 0) {
    return str.substring(0, 4) + " " + str.substring(4, 8);
  } else if (id === 1) {
    return str.substring(0, 3) + "/" + str.substring(3, 8);
  } else if (id === 2) {
    return str.substring(0, 4) + "-" + str.substring(4, 8);
  } else if (id == 3) {
    return str.substring(0, 3) + "," + str.substring(3, 8);
  }
}
```

So for example `f(0, "ABCDEFGH")` will return `"ABCD EFGH"`. I need an inverse function that uses the function `f(id, str)` to come up with inputs from the output. So `finverse(formattedStr)` should return a dictionary of the corresponding inputs. For example, `finverse("ABCD EFGH")` should return `{  id: 0, str: "ABCDEFGH" }`. Would it be possible to make use of the existing function `f` to write this inverse such that even if I were to update the original function with an extra "else if" clause, I wouldn't have to update `finverse`. In other words I do not want to manually construct `finverse` with if statements to map the outputs back to the inputs, rather I want to manipulate the original function somehow to come up with an inverse. Is this possible in javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with a slight re-factoring, the task is actually pretty simple. You don't need all those ifs, and actually, ifs run slower than Object property lookup, not to mention them not being sealed-up in a private function somewhere...

we can accomplish a translation ( 1 in, 1+ out) without any flow logic:

```
// replace all the IF logic with an externally-modifiable logic table:
f.lut=[ [4," "], [3,"/"], [4,"-"], [3,","]  ]; //(id=index, 0=pos, 1=char)


// simplify f() using the table to make choices instead of conditionals:
function f(id, str) {
   id = f.lut[id];
   return str.substring(0, id[0]) + id[1] + str.substring(id[0], 8);
}


// use the same table in reverse to compose an inverse function:
function finverse(s){
    return  {
       id:   +f.lut.map(function(A,i){ return A[1]==s.split(/[\w]+/).filter(Boolean)[0] ? 
                         String(i):
                         ""
             }).filter(Boolean)[0][0], 
       str:  s.split(/[\W]+/).filter(Boolean).join('')
    };
 }


// first, test new version of f():
 f(0, "ABCDEFGH") // ABCD EFGH
 f(1, "ABCDEFGH") // ABC/DEFGH
 f(2, "ABCDEFGH") // ABCD-EFGH
 f(3, "ABCDEFGH") // ABC,DEFGH


// now, test the inverse:
finverse("ABCD EFGH")   //{id:0, str:"ABCDEFGH"}
finverse("ABC/DEFGH")   //{id:1, str:"ABCDEFGH"}
finverse("ABCD-EFGH")   //{id:2, str:"ABCDEFGH"}
finverse("ABC,DEFGH")   //{id:3, str:"ABCDEFGH"}
```

let us know if this isn't what you were wanting, i wasn't 100% sure...

Comment: I wasn't aware of the `.filter(Boolean)` shorthand, nice one. Apparently this'll also work in ES6 with arrow functions: `.filter((x)=>!!x)`. Actually no need to wrap the arg in parentheses either: `.filter(x=>!!x)`

Comment: @cssimsek: `.filter(x=>x)` would achieve the same as `.filter(Boolean)` in ES6 ;)

Comment: That's neat, so no need to cast with `!!`; the value assigned to `x` on each iteration is implicitly converted to its boolean value..

Comment: `Array.prototype.boolFilter = function(){
      return Array.prototype.filter.call(this,x=>x);
}; ` _from the sublime to the ridiculous. :p_

Answer (score 1):

There is really no way to make it work perfectly. That is impossible to implement with nice speed characteristic. So, I try to give you two ways of solving this problem:

1. Make global object named `fRules` with rules which used in `f()`.

   ```
   fRules = [
     { 
        id: 0,
        char: ' ',
        insertPosition: 4
     },

     // ... other rules ...
   ];
   ```

   Then you can use `fRules` in `f()` simply finding rule with needed `id` and in `fInverse` iterating over array of rules and finding good one. Now you don't need to change `f()`, only `fRules()`;
2. `f.toString()` to get text of function and parse function to abstract syntax tree with something. Like inner functions of UglifyJs. Read more [here](http://css.dzone.com/articles/parsing-javascript-javascript). Then you must manually write some inverser based on your function syntax tree. Ugly idea

Comment: You can also obtain the inverse using a computer algebra system, since some JavaScript functions can be converted into mathematical expressions and vice-versa.